# managing NSUserDefaults

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

I would like to know of it's right to set `NSUserDefaults` everywhere they need to be used as compared to having a central place where they are managed. For example, in my game, in the `GamePlayScene` class I set `NSUserDeflaults` for the score and level and in the Settings class I set `NSUserDefaults` for the sound effects. These are just a few of the `NSUserDefaults` I set. If having a central place (class) where they are managed is a good idea, where should it be located (class) and how should I manage them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is a keyed archive. A good design would likely use one of these approaches:

- Declare const NSString* objects (the keys) in a global header and access NSUserDefaults directly from any code using the const strings instead of in-place @".." strings (prone to typos).
- Write a simple wrapper around NSUserDefaults with class methods like `+(void)setScore:(int)score`  to set the score without needing to know which key is used to store the score.

The more complex your project the better the second approach becomes, as the overhead of creating additional methods is reduced in favor of fewer errors, usually by using the wrong key for a value (ie storing score with the level key).

Answer (score 0):

The UserDefaults are cached in memory and are only written when you synchronize them. You can write to them anywhere you wish. Centralising this can make things more complex than is needed.

The important thing is to synchronize them at the correct moments. When the app is deactivated or killed.

The UserDefaults already IS a centralised place to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"stringValue" forKey:@"strkey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSString *str=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"strkey"];
NSlog(@"string is-%@",str);
```